# scrollView with webView not scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create an app to display various document formats and have the following code in a ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768 , 1024)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768 , 1024)];
    [scrollView addSubview:webView];

    [webView loadRequest:service.urlRequest];
}
```

The trouble is, the app is only to be used in portrait mode and one of the Word documents is  1024 wide. I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally to see the whole document but this doesn't work.

I think I need to implement some setting on the scrollview but so far haven't been able to figure out what it is.

I've tried setting the width of both the scrollView and webView widths to `1024` and `scrollView.contentSize.width` but appear to be barking up the wrong tree.

I've also tired `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 1024);` but feel as though I'm just trying various things in an almost random manner to see if one works.

Can anyone tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```